Jhipster 8: call subgenerators by command line
I've created a JHipster blueprint based on JHipster 7.9.3 and now I'm trying to convert it to JHipster 8.
I used to run my subgenerators via command line like "jhipster-my-blueprint my-subgenerator" but now I face a fatal error "my-subgenerator is not a known command".
I'm not sure if this is the new reality or if I missed something during this process of converting.
Thanks
